# Django 403 Error csrf_token incorrect even when form contains it

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have an issue with my login form which is custom login form, and the issue us that when I login it gets stuck on processing requests and if I click on login twice I get a 403 error saying csrf_token is missing, however, I do have it.

This is my login form:

```
      <form method="POST" action="{% url 'main:user_login' %}" class="form-signin">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-label-group">
          <input type="text" name="username" id="inputText" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
          <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-label-group">
         <input type="password"  name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>   
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Remember password</label>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="form-control" name="" value="Login">
        <hr class="my-4">
        <p>Don't have account? <a href="{% url 'main:signup' %}" id="signup">Sign up here</a></p>
        <a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}" id="signup">Forgot Password</a>
        {% if form.errors %}
        <p style="color: red;">Sorry, the username or password you entered is incorrect please try again</p>
        {% endif %}
      </form>
```

This is my login view:

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home:home')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'main/user_login.html', context={'form': form})
```

I cannot figure out why this is happening, is it because of my form error or my login view? 
I am using a custom user model and I have already set that to Auth.user in setting. Login works fine after I go back from error page and input credentials again. However, on the first run login gets stuck on processing request.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: These are the exact sequence of events:

1. All tabs have closed user has not logged in anywhere, server isn't running anywhere.
2. Server starts running and user goes to 127.0.0.1:8000 which is the login page (In the website the main page is the login page)
3. User inputs username and password
4. Chrome is stuck on 'processing request...'
5. User clicks on login button again
6. Django error page ' Forbidden 403 pops up'
7. User clicks on the back button
8. User inputs credentials again
9. User can now successfully log in

These are the step by step on how this issue is I will appreciate any help!

Comment: See [this explanation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/#why-might-a-user-encounter-a-csrf-validation-failure-after-logging-in) in the FAQ/

Comment: I have looked at that but I cannot find how I can resolve the issue, @alasdair can you clarify where is the issue?